# Getting empty string on h:selectOneMenu

Tags: hibernate, jsf, javabeans

I do not know why it is empty because I have the same piece of code in my system for a user register.
This is mu xhtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/template/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <!--h:outputScript name="js/myjs.js" /-->
        <h1 class="page-header text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Denunciar
        </h1>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h:form id="cadastrarDenuncia" styleClass="form-horizontal" p:role="form">

                <!-- Número de denuncias -->
                <h:inputHidden value="#{denunciaBean.denuncia.ndenuncia}"/> 

                <!-- Tabs para visualizacao -->
                <p:wizard flowListener="#{denunciaBean.onFlowProcess}">

                    <!-- Tipos de Crime -->
                    <p:tab id="tabtipocrime" title="Local do Crime">
                        <div class="form-group panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                           <h:outputLabel for="idTipoCrime" class="col-md-4 control-label">Tipo de Crime: </h:outputLabel>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                             <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="idTipoCrime" value="#{denunciaBean.denuncia.tipoCrime}" required="true" requiredMessage="Campo obrigatório!">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Roubo" itemLabel="Roubo"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Furto" itemLabel="Furto"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="TraficoEntorpecentes" itemLabel="Tráfico de Entorpecentes"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Homicidio" itemLabel="Homicídio"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Latrocinio" itemLabel="Latrocício"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Receptacao" itemLabel="Receptação"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Estupro" itemLabel="Estupro"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Quadrilha" itemLabel="Quadrilha"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="CrimeAmbiental" itemLabel="Crime Ambiental"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Sequestro" itemLabel="Sequestro"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="ViolenciaDomestica" itemLabel="Violência Doméstica"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Assassinato" itemLabel="Assassinato"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Agressao" itemLabel="Agressão"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Ameaca" itemLabel="Ameaça"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Pedofilia" itemLabel="Pedofilia"/>
                             </h:selectOneMenu>
                           </div>
                           <div class="text-danger"><h:message for="idTipoCrime"/></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </p:tab>

                    <!-- Local do Crime-->
                    <p:tab id="tabcrimelocal" title="Local do Crime">
                        <!-- Se der tempo pegar o local do ususário atraves do ip 
                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517667/how-to-mark-users-current-location-on-primefaces-gmap
                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415851/best-way-to-get-geo-location-in-java
                        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.maxmind.geoip/geoip-api/1.3.1
                        -->
                        <div class="form-group panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h:outputLabel class="col-md-4 control-label">Clique no local aproximado do acontecimento: </h:outputLabel>

                            <p:growl id="mensagem"  showDetail="true" />

                            <p:gmap id="idmapcrimelocal" center="-10.9232843, -37.0501223" zoom="15" type="HYBRID"  widgetVar="idmapcrimelocal" style="width:470px; height:300px" onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);">
                            </p:gmap>
                            <p:remoteCommand name="onPoint" actionListener="#{denunciaBean.onPointSelect}" update="mensagem" />

                            <h:inputHidden id="lat" value="#{denunciaBean.denuncia.latitude}" />
                            <h:inputHidden id="lng" value="#{denunciaBean.denuncia.longitude}" />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </p:tab>

                    <!-- Outras Informacoes -->
                    <p:tab id="tabextrainformation" title="Observações">
                        <div class="form-group panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- Data e Hora do Crime -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h:outputLabel class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idDataHoraCrime">Data e Hora do crime: </h:outputLabel>
                            <div class="col-md-4">  
                                <h:inputText id="data" label="Data e Hora do Crime" value="#{denunciaBean.denuncia.dataHoraCrime}"
                                size="16" maxlength="16" required="true">
                                    <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="long" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" /> 
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 control-label text-danger"><h:message for="idDataHoraCrime"/></div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Observacoes-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h:outputLabel class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idObservacao">Observações: </h:outputLabel>  
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h:inputTextarea class="form-control input-md" value="#{denunciaBean.denuncia.observacao}" id="idObservacao" placeholder="Observacao"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 control-label text-danger"><h:message for="idObservacao"/></div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Botões -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idConfirmar"></label>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h:commandButton id="idConfirmarBt" styleClass="btn btn-primary" action="#{denunciaBean.salvar}" value="Confirmar"
                                onclick="if (!confirm('Confirmar denúncia?')) return false;"/>
                            <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-danger" value="Cancelar" onclick="redirecionar()"/>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:wizard>
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAj8u8gZyCkVaMTiRcTXWclFgs0s7sv2nY&amp;" />
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function handlePointClick(event) {

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    browserSupportFlag = true;
                    var latlng = event.latLng;
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'latLng' : latlng
                    }, function(results, status) {
                        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            onPoint([ {
                                name : 'lng',
                                value : event.latLng.lng()
                            }, {
                                name : 'lat',
                                value : event.latLng.lat()
                            } ]);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

This is the class

```
package br.com.smartpatrolling.denuncia;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import br.com.smartpatrolling.usuario.Usuario;

@Entity
@Table(name = "denuncia")
public class Denuncia implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -387555820515169694L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer ndenuncia;
    @ManyToOne
    // Permite excluir todas as denuncias do usuario ao excluir um usuário
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Usuario usuario;
    private String tipoCrime;
    /** Local do crime */
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String observacao;
    /** Data e hora aproximados do crime */
    private Date dataHoraCrime;
    /** Data e hora do cadastro da denuncia */
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date dataHoraCadastro;

    public Integer getNdenuncia() {
        return ndenuncia;
    }

    public void setNdenuncia(Integer ndenuncia) {
        this.ndenuncia = ndenuncia;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getTipoCrime() {
        return tipoCrime;
    }

    public void setTipoCrime(String tipoCrime) {
        this.tipoCrime = tipoCrime;
    }

    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }

    public Date getDataHoraCrime() {
        return dataHoraCrime;
    }

    public void setDataHoraCrime(Date dataHoraCrime) {
        this.dataHoraCrime = dataHoraCrime;
    }

    public Date getDataHoraCadastro() {
        return dataHoraCadastro;
    }

    public void setDataHoraCadastro(Date dataHoraCadastro) {
        this.dataHoraCadastro = dataHoraCadastro;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((dataHoraCadastro == null) ? 0 : dataHoraCadastro.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dataHoraCrime == null) ? 0 : dataHoraCrime.hashCode());
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(latitude);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(longitude);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((ndenuncia == null) ? 0 : ndenuncia.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((observacao == null) ? 0 : observacao.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((tipoCrime == null) ? 0 : tipoCrime.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((usuario == null) ? 0 : usuario.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Denuncia other = (Denuncia) obj;
        if (dataHoraCadastro == null) {
            if (other.dataHoraCadastro != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dataHoraCadastro.equals(other.dataHoraCadastro))
            return false;
        if (dataHoraCrime == null) {
            if (other.dataHoraCrime != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dataHoraCrime.equals(other.dataHoraCrime))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(latitude) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.latitude))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(longitude) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.longitude))
            return false;
        if (ndenuncia == null) {
            if (other.ndenuncia != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ndenuncia.equals(other.ndenuncia))
            return false;
        if (observacao == null) {
            if (other.observacao != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!observacao.equals(other.observacao))
            return false;
        if (tipoCrime == null) {
            if (other.tipoCrime != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!tipoCrime.equals(other.tipoCrime))
            return false;
        if (usuario == null) {
            if (other.usuario != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!usuario.equals(other.usuario))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is the bean

```
package br.com.smartpatrolling.web;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;


import br.com.smartpatrolling.denuncia.Denuncia;
import br.com.smartpatrolling.denuncia.DenunciaRN;

@ManagedBean(name = "denunciaBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DenunciaBean {

    private Denuncia denuncia = new Denuncia();
    private List<Denuncia> lista = null;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{contextoBean}")
    private ContextoBean contextoBean;

    public String salvar() {
        this.denuncia.setUsuario(this.contextoBean.getUsuarioLogado());
        DenunciaRN denunciaRN = new DenunciaRN();
        denunciaRN.salvar(this.denuncia);
        this.denuncia = new Denuncia();
        this.lista = null;
        return "minhasDenuncias";
    }

    public String excluir() {
        DenunciaRN denunciaRN = new DenunciaRN();
        denunciaRN.excluir(this.denuncia);
        this.denuncia = new Denuncia();
        this.lista = null;
        return null;
    }

    public List<Denuncia> getLista() {
        if (this.lista == null){
            DenunciaRN denunciaRN = new DenunciaRN();
            this.lista = denunciaRN.listarDenuncias(this.contextoBean.getUsuarioLogado());
        }
        return lista;
    }

    public void onPointSelect(ActionEvent event) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Point Selected", "Lat:" + denuncia.getLatitude() + ", Long:" + denuncia.getLongitude()));
    }



    public void setLista(List<Denuncia> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public Denuncia getDenuncia() {
        return denuncia;
    }

    public void setDenuncia(Denuncia denuncia) {
        this.denuncia = denuncia;
    }

    public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {
            return event.getNewStep();
    }

    public ContextoBean getContextoBean() {
        return contextoBean;
    }

    public void setContextoBean(ContextoBean contextoBean) {
        this.contextoBean = contextoBean;
    }
}
```

This is my data base when i make a dennounce. tipocrime is empty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ilO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I was using @RequestScoped instead of @ViewScoped in my bean.